# Some htaccess issue: why doesn't it work?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have weblink: `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/00001` & files are in `/var/www/html/00001` folder.

`index.php` works perfect.

However, some internal links like /img/logo.png don't work - website is looking them on `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/img/logo.png`.

So I have added .htaccess file (mod_rewrite enabled & ok).

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !00001/
RewriteRule (.*) /00001/$1 [L]

DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Why doesn't it work? How to fix an issue?

Comment: How did you test mod_rewrite was working? The rule seems ok ... https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=118faa4a-e635-576b-b327-79c73a79ab08

Comment: @MatthewPage Thank you for your support! Thanks for your post I have known new excellent feature for testing  .htaccess. I have found my dummy bug, I was placed  .htaccess inside of 00001 folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found my dummy bug, I was placed .htaccess inside of 00001 folder, so as soon as I have placed it in main folder,  everything works well.